# Addressing "procrastination" in minimax

Tags: minimax

I'm implementing minimax for a small game and am noticing something that I'm calling "procrastination".  Boiled down to a very simple example:

In a capture-the-flag game, the flag is one square UP from player A, and player B is 50 spaces away. It's A's turn, and he can search 6 moves ahead. What I'm seeing is that all possible moves have a value of "Win" since A knows he can get to the flag before B even if he doesn't grab it immediately. So if UP is the last move in the ordering, he'll just go LEFT and RIGHT for a while until B is within striking distance and then he has to finally get the flag.

At first the behavior looked like a bug, but stepping through it I convinced myself that each move really is a "Win", but the behavior is not good. I could influence the evaluation by making a flag captured 4 moves from now less valuable than a flag captured now, but I wondered if there was an aspect to the minimax search than I'm missing? Is there the any concept of a high score earlier being most desirable than an equally high score obtained only later?

Comment: Lol, you made a troll game...! :P

Comment: Exactly what I thought. Didn't expect quite the attitude from my 15 line algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the minimax search itself that would make winning sooner preferable.  Since all terminal positions evaluate to the same score, the algorithm effectively chooses a move at random.  Make your evaluation function decrease the winning score slightly for each level deeper in the tree where it is called and minimax will choose to win sooner.